# select value from object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am getting dificulties to select value from this dictionary,

my object

```
[{id: "063f48d0-1452-4dad-8421-145820ddf0f8", 
 storeName: "birr", 
 cost: {
         4fd5ee28-835d-42dc-85a6-699a37bc1948: "54",
         f45827c8-1b1a-48c3-831b-56dab9bcaf3b: "543"
       }, 
 saved: true}]
```

I need to get cost of 54 somehow.

please help

Comment: Do you have the `4fd5ee28...` key to retrieve it with, do you always want the first cost (with order potentially being undefined), or what exactly? What have you tried, what problem are you having?

Comment: I need dynamically select cost for this store, as you can see I have couple costs to choose from. i do have this `4fd5ee28` from other dropdown list object,

Comment: when I do `Object.keys(stores[0].cost)[0]` it selects that id only, how to get to value?

Comment: it's just an array/object combo. `foo[0]->cost['4fdd5...']`. if you'd `console.log(foo)` you'd be shown the exact structure/path to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script>
    var arraylist = [{'id': "063f48d0-1452-4dad-8421-145820ddf0f8", 
        'storeName': "birr", 
        'cost': {
        '4fd5ee28-835d-42dc-85a6-699a37bc1948': "54",
        'f45827c8-1b1a-48c3-831b-56dab9bcaf3b': "543"
        }, 
        'saved': true}];
    
    var costKey = '4fd5ee28-835d-42dc-85a6-699a37bc1948'
    var selectedCost = arraylist[0]['cost'][costKey];
    alert(selectedCost);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GUIDs in `cost` need to be inside quotes.

```
        var obj = [{id: "063f48d0-1452-4dad-8421-145820ddf0f8", 
            storeName: "birr", 
            cost: {
                '4fd5ee28-835d-42dc-85a6-699a37bc1948': "54",
                'f45827c8-1b1a-48c3-831b-56dab9bcaf3b': "543"
        }, 
            saved: true
        }]

        document.write(obj[0].cost['4fd5ee28-835d-42dc-85a6-699a37bc1948']);
```

That outputs the value 54.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your keys are in quotes. Otherwise to retrieve the value it is simply a matter of accessing it like object[key] as the following code demonstrates.

```
var stores = [{id: "063f48d0-1452-4dad-8421-145820ddf0f8", 
    storeName: "birr", 
    cost: {
         '4fd5ee28-835d-42dc-85a6-699a37bc1948': "54",
        'f45827c8-1b1a-48c3-831b-56dab9bcaf3b': "543"
    }, 
    saved: true
}];

var store = stores[0];
var cost = store.cost;
var key = Object.keys(cost)[0];
var value = cost[key];
console.log(value);
```